# Treepanel with rootVisible = true not shown

Tags: extjs, root, extjs4.1, treepanel

My tree is shown correctly when using `rootVisible: false`. However setting it to `true` leads to no tree display and no error.

My aim is to show a root node that I can define as `/` or `Root`. How to achieve this?

---

My solution:

Putting `rootVisible` to `true` and adding this to my tree store:

```
root: {
               id       : '/',
               expanded : false,
               name     : '/',
               type     : 'folder',
               path     : '/',
               root     : true
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name for the Rootnode is `Root` by default. But you can specify any other name.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    root: {
        text: "/",
        expanded: true,
        children: [
            { text: "detention", leaf: true },
            { text: "homework", expanded: true, children: [
                { text: "book report", leaf: true },
                { text: "alegrbra", leaf: true}
            ] },
            { text: "buy lottery tickets", leaf: true }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

If this don't help please post more code from your data send by the server, TreeStore, reader.

Comment: Thanks I made it and have posted my solution.

Comment: @Azincourt I recommend to not use string values as `id`. Use a number, for example 0 if possible. The support for string Id's is bad within ExtJS.

Comment: Thanks changed it. Another question: After adding a node, I want to refresh my tree, or even better, refresh only the changed part. A. How do I reload a tree fully? B. How do I refresh a tree part without reloading the whole tree?

Comment: @Azincourt If the following don't help and this comment don't answer your question this might be qualified as a new question... To reload a single node just send the load request of it's parent again to the server. The server will answer and the Treestore should handle the rest. With that only the affected nodes get rerendered.

Comment: if I use `var oStore = Ext.getStore('treeStore'); oStore.load();` after changing the tree, then my whole store gets loaded and the subfolder is put on root level. And how do I send the load request of the parent? you mean `oStore.load('/subfolder');` ?

Comment: @Azincourt Iam doing somthing like this: `treeStore.load({node: me.selectedNode});` while my backend reads the node Id and send back it's childrens